# PNP for estimating 360 camera pose from equirectangular image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, 360-panorama

I have an equirectangular image (Created from a 360 camera) and several 2D-3D correspondences, and I want to estimate the correct camera position and rotation.

Preferably using OpenCV

Comment: what is the question? what are the things you tried that didn't work?